# Can't update an Entity in Room Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-room

I need to update an entire entity, so I tried with @Update but it doesn't work, And with the UPDATE query there are too many fields. So what could I do?

```
@Update
updatePackage(item: Package)

@Query("UPDATE PackageEntity SET weight = :weight ...[[TOO MANY FIELDS]] WHERE id = :id")

    @Entity
    data class PackageEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id: Int? = -1,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "weight") var weight: Double = 0.0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "unitType") var unitType: Options.UnitTypes = Options.UnitTypes.MT,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "high") var high: Number = 0.0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "length") var length: Number = 0.0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "wide") var wide: Number = 0.0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "quantity") var quantity: Int = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "description") var description: String = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "loadType") var loadType: Options.LoadTypes = Options.LoadTypes.GENERAL,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "cityOrigin") var cityOrigin: SimpleClass = SimpleClass(),
    @ColumnInfo(name = "cityDestine") var cityDestine: SimpleClass = SimpleClass(),
    @ColumnInfo(name = "pickup")var pickup: Boolean = true,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "deliver")var deliver: Boolean = true
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Mmm that is weird... you could try something like

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun updatePackage(item: Package)
```

Comment: Insert a new one with the same ID? Could you post Package class?

Comment: Yes I have posted an edit, only update method doesn't work, because insert, delete and querys are normal

Comment: Try to change PK to `@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Long` and try with `@Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)`. It's very weird that not function